# Database error when i tried to add states in 'Default Tax Destination Calculation'

Tags: database, error, country-regions

I am trying to add the States of India through database so that it will be available under the option system->configuration->sales->tax/Default Tax Destination Calculation in magento 1.9.2.2.

I logged into cPanel. Then to database and then to `directory_country_region` table and clicked on the SQL tab and added the following code

```
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` VALUES
(NULL , 'IN', 'AN','Andaman and Nicobar Islands'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'AP','Andhra Pradesh'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'AR','Arunachal Pradesh'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'AS','Assam'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'BR','Bihar'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'CH','Chandigarh'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'CT','Chhattisgarh'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'DN','Dadra and Nagar Haveli'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'DD','Daman and Diu'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'DL','Delhi'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'GA','Goa'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'GJ','Gujarat'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'HR','Haryana'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'HP','Himachal Pradesh'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'JK','Jammu and Kashmir'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'JH','Jharkhand'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'KA','Karnataka'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'KL','Kerala'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'LD','Lakshadweep'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'MP','Madhya Pradesh'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'MH','Maharashtra'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'MN','Manipur'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'ML','Meghalaya'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'MZ','Mizoram'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'NL','Nagaland'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'OR','Odisha'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'PY','Puducherry'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'PB','Punjab'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'RJ','Rajasthan'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'SK','Sikkim'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'TN','Tamil Nadu'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'TG','Telangana'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'TR','Tripura'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'UP','Uttar Pradesh'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'UT','Uttarakhand'),
(NULL , 'IN', 'WB','West Bengal');
```

Now I am getting the error,

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `` 'INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` VALUES
>   (NULL , 'IN', 'AN','Andaman and N' `` at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Under the Sql, there was a query

```
SELECT * FROM `directory_country_region` WHERE 1
```

Under which I inserted my query. so there was an error stating:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'INSERT INTO directory_country_region VALUES
>   (NULL , 'IN', 'AN','Andaman and N'` at line 2

Now I removed the 'where 1' from previous query and places a semicolon at end of the line. And I got my issue resolved and Now I see the States are available at the backend. 
The change I made:

```
SELECT * FROM `directory_country_region`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL Clause to insert multiple row in single query.

```
INSERT INTO Table_name (ID, Name)
SELECT 123, 'Rahul'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 124, 'Pravin' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 125, 'John';
```